# Image_tag not including full asset_host value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

**config/environment/development.rb**

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

**myMailer.rb**

```
<%= image_tag @service_request.service_photo_1 %>
```

**In the email this renders as:**

```
<img alt="Img_0134" src="http:/uploads/service_request/service_photo_1/44/IMG_0134.jpg">
```

Which is the correct source path for `@service_request.service_photo_1` except it should start with `http://localhost:3000`. I've looked at similar questions here on the site and most folks seem to have issues with the image source missing the entire asset_host value (i.e. `src="/images/img_123.jpg"`). However, I seem to have a partial asset_host value (the `http:`shows up in my `src` path). Any thoughts? Is there something wrong with setting the asset_host to `localhost:3000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this one myself. I needed to restart the WEBrick local server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Always always always. Always.